# SQL Server stored procedures questions

Tags: sql-server

I got simple 2 SQL Server stored procedure questions that need your help. I'm a newbie to SQL Server, so I got stuck with very simple syntax errors when I execute my code

1. I got a table as below and I need to create a stored procedure named `count_status` that accepts a single argument and returns only the total number of animals of a particular conversation status and the code should not return the corresponding conservation status.

Species table

[image: Species table]

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE count_status 
     @ConservationStatus INT
AS
  SELECT COUNT(ID) 
  FROM Species 
  WHERE ConservationStatus = @ConservationStatus
GO;
END
```

And I got a syntax error for the above code. Could you help me with this?

Thanks

2. Create a stored procedure named `format_currency` that accepts a character and a double number. It will return a `varchar(32)` with the symbol in the front, followed by the number to 2 decimal places. For example `format_currency ('$',123.4)` should return `$123.4`

I don't know how to write code for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Learn to ask technical questions in a smart way. If you encounter an error - post the complete error message. So - what is the error? And what does "DELIMITER //" mean or imply? Is that actual code in your script?

Comment: SMor: it is in one of my tests so the "DELIMITER //" was defaulted in the sql interpreter. I have no idea why it is there. but I couldn't delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE count_status 
     @ConservationStatus INT
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(ID) 
  FROM Species 
  WHERE ConservationStatus = @ConservationStatus
END
GO;
```

> Explanation : 
>   1) Use Begin After As 'this begins the procedure query'
>   2) Use Go After end

Comment: Thanks Ravi. Can we omit "BEGIN" and "END" ? are they mostly used for Functions only?

Comment: its part of procedure. Indicate from where the procedure start and ends

Answer (score 0):

For #1, I haven't tested this but I think you need to use a group by clause

```
CREATE PROCEDURE count_status @ConservationStatus int
AS
SELECT COUNT(ID) 
FROM   Species 
WHERE  ConservationStatus = @ConservationStatus
GROUP  BY ConservationStatus
GO;
```

For #2, note the input parm is decimal (12, 2), that defines 2 decimal places which should both pad anything like 123.1 and trim anything like 123.123

```
ALTER  FUNCTION format_currency
(
    @currency_symbol varchar(1),
    @currency_amount decimal(12, 2)
)
RETURNS varchar(12)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @currency_symbol + ltrim(cast(cast(@currency_amount as money) as varchar))
END
GO
```

if you have a current version of Sql Server you can also use this

```
ALTER  FUNCTION format_currency
(
    @currency_symbol varchar(1),
    @currency_amount decimal(12, 2)
)
RETURNS varchar(32)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN '$' + FORMAT(@currency_amount,'#,###,##0.00')
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks vscoder. For #2, do we need to create format_currency before? As we don't have any function before so I just thought of creating a procedure using CREATE PROC instead.

Comment: Yes, you need to create format_currency, change this ALTER FUNCTION to CREATE FUNCTION. A proc, or procedure, is a different type of object. Generally functions have a narrow focus, they do one small thing, procedures are for executing multiple steps.

Answer (score 0):

In this way we can solve the second task using stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE format_currency 
    @symbol CHAR(1),
    @amount DECIMAL(18, 2),
    @fin_out VARCHAR(32) out
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @formatted_amount VARCHAR(32);

    SET @formatted_amount = CONCAT(@symbol, FORMAT(@amount, '0.00'));

    SELECT @formatted_amount AS FormattedCurrency;
END
GO

--To see the result
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(32)
EXEC format_currency '$', 123.4, @result OUTPUT;
```

Hope it helps.